# Lots of trouble with CreateProcess and MapViewOfFile

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-studio-2010

It has been bugging me for hours now and I can't solve this problem.

I have been coding so far without much problems. My task is to send messages through a circular file from one process to another. The messages are generated by a thread in the first process, sent through shared memory to another thread in this process, and then the thread sends this message to the separated process. I was able to create the child process and send some messages to it, but when I started implementing the semaphores to make the circular file, things went south.

The code is heavy and though I'm using c++, it is structured, so a little hard to understand, and a little messy. Once I get it right I'll start cleaning it up.

This is thread a from process 1:

```
DWORD WINAPI StRetFunc(LPVOID id)
{
    LONG LPrevCount;
    HANDLE pFile;
    HANDLE pSent;
    HANDLE pRecieved;
    char* pImage;
    BOOL endThread = false;

    unsigned int pPos=0;
    BOOL bStatus;
    STARTUPINFO si;         // StartUpInformation for new process
    PROCESS_INFORMATION NewProcess; // New Process infos

    pFile = CreateFileMapping(
        (HANDLE)0xFFFFFFFF,
        NULL,
        PAGE_READWRITE,     // access type
        0,                  // dwMaximumSizeHigh
        BYTE_TAM_ARQ,                   // dwMaximumSizeLow
        (LPCWSTR) "CircFile");          // name

    check(pFile, "Cannot open file.");

    pSent = CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, (LPCWSTR) "SentMSG");
    check(pSent, "Cannot create event SentMSG (pSent).");

    pRecieved = CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, (LPCWSTR) "RecievedMSG");
    check(pRecieved, "Cannot create event RecievedMSG (pRecieved)");

    cout << "Handles created\n";

    LPWSTR szCmdline = _tcsdup(TEXT("..\\Debug\\ATR TP - LS.exe"));
    ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
    si.cb = sizeof(si); // Tamanho da estrutura em bytes
    si.dwFlags = CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE;

    bStatus = CreateProcess(
        szCmdline , // Nome
        NULL,   // linha de comando
        NULL,   // atributos de segurança: Processo
        NULL,   // atributos de segurança: Thread
        FALSE,  // herança de handles
        CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE, // CreationFlags
        //NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS,
        NULL,   // lpEnvironment
        NULL,   // diretório corrente do filho
        &si,            // lpStartUpInfo
        &NewProcess);   // lpProcessInformation
    check(bStatus, "Impossivel criar processo: %s", DecodeError());

    while(WaitForSingleObject(hEvent_Esc, 0) != WAIT_OBJECT_0) {
        CheckFreezeEvent(stretEvent, "Retira Status");
        WaitForSingleObject(stretSemaphore, INFINITE);
        {
            do {

                while(circ_mem[stret_index].empty() == true)
                        ++stret_index %= MAX_LISTA_CIRC;
                while(memrdy[stret_index] == false);
                if(circ_mem[stret_index].substr(7, 3) == "000")
                    break;
                else
                    ++stret_index %= MAX_LISTA_CIRC;

                if(WaitForSingleObject(hEvent_Esc, 0) == WAIT_OBJECT_0) {
                    endThread = true;
                    break;
                }
                if(WaitForSingleObject(stretEvent, 0) != WAIT_OBJECT_0)
                    CheckFreezeEvent(stretEvent, "Retira Status");

            } while(true);
            if(endThread) break;
            CheckFreezeEvent(stretEvent, "Retira Status");
            cout << "Status Retirado: " << circ_mem[stret_index] << " Na posicao: " << stret_index << "\n";

            //WriteToFile

            pImage = (char*) MapViewOfFile(
                pFile,
                FILE_MAP_WRITE,
                0,
                0,
                35);

            strcpy(pImage, circ_mem[stret_index].c_str());
            SetEvent(pSent);
            while(WaitForSingleObject(pRecieved, 0) != WAIT_OBJECT_0 ) {
                if(WaitForSingleObject(hEvent_Esc, 0)) break;
            }
            ResetEvent(pRecieved);

            circ_mem[stret_index].clear();

            memrdy[stret_index] = false;
            ReleaseSemaphore(iSemaphore, 1, &LPrevCount);
        }
    }

    cout << "Encerrando Thread Retirada Status\n";
    CloseHandle(pFile);
    CloseHandle(pSent);
    CloseHandle(pRecieved);

    return(0);
}
```

and this is the child process

```
// ATR TP - LS.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "FileFuncs.h"
#include "..\ATR TP\debug.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    BOOL bStatus;
    char *lpImage;          // Apontador para imagem local
    HANDLE pFile;
    HANDLE pEventSent;
    HANDLE pEventRead;
    HANDLE hEsc;


    pFile= OpenFileMapping(
        FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS,
        FALSE,              // Handle herdável
        (LPCWSTR) "CircFile");          // Escolha o seu nome preferido
    check(pFile, "Nao foi possivel abrir file mapping: %s", DecodeError());

    lpImage= (char *)MapViewOfFile(
        pFile,
        FILE_MAP_WRITE,     // Direitos de acesso: leitura e escrita
        0,                  // dwOffsetHigh
        0,                  // dwOffset Low
        BYTE_TAM_ARQ);          // Número de bytes a serem mapeados
    check(lpImage, "Impossivel criar map view.");

    // Abre eventos criados

    hEsc = OpenEvent(EVENT_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, (LPCWSTR) "myEsc");
    check(hEsc, "Impossivel abrir evento ESC: %d\n", GetLastError());

    pEventSent= OpenEvent(EVENT_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, (LPCWSTR) "SentMSG");
    check(pEventSent, "Impossivel abrir evento SentMSG: %d\n", GetLastError());

    // Cria evento com reset automático
    pEventRead= OpenEvent(EVENT_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, (LPCWSTR) "RecievedMSG");
    check(pEventRead, "Impossivel abrir evento RecievedMSG: %d\n", GetLastError());

    cout << "[Exibicao] Handles Abertos" << endl;

    bool endProg = false;

    while(WaitForSingleObject(hEsc, 0) != WAIT_OBJECT_0) {
        // Espera que processo A escreva mensagem 
        while(WaitForSingleObject(pEventSent, 0) != WAIT_OBJECT_0) {
            if(WaitForSingleObject(hEsc, 0) == WAIT_OBJECT_0) endProg = true;
        }
        if(endProg) break;
        ResetEvent(pEventSent);
        if (strcmp(lpImage, "")==0) break;
        printf("[Exibicao] Mensagem Status Recebida= %s\n", lpImage);

        // Limpa memória compartilhada
        strcpy(lpImage, "");    
        SetEvent(pEventRead);   // Avisa processo A

    }

    // Elimina mapeamento

    CloseHandle(pFile);
    CloseHandle(pEventSent);
    CloseHandle(pEventRead);

    bStatus=UnmapViewOfFile(lpImage);
    check(bStatus, "Unmap Falhou.");

    //cout << "Encerrando Processo Retirada Status ARQUIVO" << endl;
    // ^if i uncomment this line, hell breaks loose

    ExitProcess(0);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    return 0;
}
```

If I uncomment the last line containing cout in the previous file, I can't open my events and do nothing with the child process. What does cout have to do with opening my events?

Also, after I check for errors, GetLastError() gives me number 2. What does it meant o try OpenEvent and get a error number 2?

I believe strongly that the problem relies on the MapViewOfFile since I've read somewhere that if you don't get the offset and file size right (something about granularity and file not being 0 sized, that I just couldn't understand). Maybe a chunk of memory is being overwtitten and messing my program.

Check is a macro and is a modified version of what Zed's Awesome Debug Macros: http://c.learncodethehardway.org/book/ex20.html

Comment: update. It started working, but
    cout << "Encerrando Processo Retirada Status ARQUIVO" << endl;
prints a messy message

Comment: i guess this was messing up my code `si.dwFlags = CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone curious about what was happening, I was trying to create a new console through `si.dwFlags`. However, the bit setup `si.dwFlags = CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE;` is not defined by MSDN, so it is not a valid configuration. My guess is that it was messing with some relevant registers regarding memory access of the IPC, and thus messing up both the opening of handles and the actual usage of the shared memory through a File Mapping.

The correct apporach is to set `CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE` inside `CreateProcess` like it was originally posted:

```
bStatus = CreateProcess(
    szCmdline , // Nome
    NULL,   // linha de comando
    NULL,   // atributos de segurança: Processo
    NULL,   // atributos de segurança: Thread
    FALSE,  // herança de handles
    CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE, // CreationFlags
    //NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS,
    NULL,   // lpEnvironment
    NULL,   // diretório corrente do filho
    &si,            // lpStartUpInfo
    &NewProcess);   // lpProcessInformation
check(bStatus, "Impossivel criar processo: %s", DecodeError());
```

and avoid using `dwFlags` if you are unsure how to.